# Route-Me RMMarker scale marker size when user zooms in or out

Tags: objective-c, route-me

I have the following code and it works fine, shows a marker with route-me but I'm looking for a way to resize the marker every time the user zooms in or out from the map (eg. marker gets larger when you zoom in and gets smaller when you zoom out). I've looked at the function of "newMarker.contentsSize" but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there a function that will allow this ability?

```
RMMarker *newMarker;
NSString *fileLocation;
fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"marker-blue" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *startImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation];

newLocation.latitude = 47.580;
newLocation.longitude = -122.333;   
newMarker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:startImage anchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];
[mv.contents.markerManager addMarker:newMarker AtLatLong:newLocation];
newMarker = nil;
```

Comment: I haven't set any options on my RMMarkers or RMMapView that I can find that are related to this, but the behavior I see is that markers get smaller when you zoom in and bigger when you zoom out. This is exactly the opposite of the behavior one would want and expect. I've been trying to figure out a way to trace this behavior and have no ideas left.

Comment: Phill, did you measure the icon sizes with some tools or it you own senses? visually it's like you say sometimes, but for me the real markers size is the same all time